# What does "a party organization" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

This is a definition of a political machine from Encyclopedia Britannica.

political machine, in U.S. politics, **a party organization**, headed by a single boss or small autocratic group, that commands enough votes to maintain political and administrative control of a city, county, or state.

Is is just a different name for a political party?

Political party, a group of persons organized to acquire and exercise political power.

Comment: Yes, a party organization could be a political party, but it is not assigned the term "politics" yet because it is just a group of people. Think of it as a "group of people" not a "political group of people." The rest of the definition is what adds the political aspect. Although, you could infer from the nature of the text that it means political party.

Comment: Hmm, but it says that they command enough votes to have control over a city. Wouldn't that mean that they have to be a political entity?

Comment: I went on a bit of a rant, so I deleted those comments. Basically a party organization is referring to a political party, but it doesn't have to... for example the "party planning committee" on the US office could be a "party organization" (see how to definition changed) so it is the fact that is used in the context of politics (hence the proceeding disclaimer "in U.S. politics") that it refers to political party.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the sentence in teh question, the term "**party organization**" would most usually mean a group within a political party, generally the group that runs the party or soem section of the party. It could also mean a groupo outside the party that seeks to benefit the party, but this is less likely in my view.

In the two quotes given as examples in [the answer by mjjf](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/309842/91457) he term has this same meaning: an organized group that runs or is responsible for the activities of a party or a section of a party.

Tammany Hall was not the same as the Democratic party, but it exerted such strong influence on the New York City Democratic party that it could be said to have run the party in that city for a number of years.

Answer (score 1):

In the definition of political machine you have provided, party organization is either referring to an organization with a party structure, or an organization that works to benefit a particular party.

Since there could conceivably be organizations with a party structure that are not political, we cannot assume that party organizations are always the same as political parties, or even a single party since it could be a collection of parties under one overarching organization.  In some sentences, *organization* could be referring to an activity, such as organizing a child's birthday party, rather than an institution.

Also note that [Tammany Hall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tammany_Hall) was a famous political machine, and while it benefited the Democratic party, it was not itself a party.

Examples:

- This sentence from the 1933 article [*The Political Party vs the Political Machine*](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1177/000271623316900104?journalCode=anna):

> The term 'political machine' is used to convey an unfavorable impression regarding a given **party organization**.

- This sentence from the [Federal Election Commission of the US website](https://www.fec.gov/help-candidates-and-committees/registering-political-party/information-local-party-committees-not-registered-fec/#:%7E:text=A%20local%20party%20organization%20is,district%20or%20local%20party%20committee.):

> A local **party organization** is an organization that is responsible for a political party's activities below the state level (such as city, county or district level) but is not registered with the Federal Election Commission (FEC) as a district or local party committee.